# Exchange ews managed api create item in public folder

Tags: c#, vb.net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have written the following VB code to create a contact using the Exchange managed API.  It creates a contact in the default "contacts" folder within the inbox.  However I need to know how to modify it to save the contact into a public folder. 
If anyone knows how to do it in C# feel free to reply as I can translate back to VB.

```
Function create_contact()
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AddressOf ValidateCertificate)
    Dim service As New ExchangeService(requestedServerVersion:=ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1)
    'Add a valid EWS service end point here or user Autodiscover

    service.Url = New Uri("https://server/ews/exchange.asmx")

    'Add a valid user credentials

    service.Credentials = New WebCredentials("username", "password", "domain")

    'To address the SSL challenge

    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AddressOf ValidateCertificate)

    Try


        Dim contact As Contact = New Contact(service)

        contact.GivenName = "Brian"
        contact.MiddleName = "David"
        contact.Surname = "Johnson"
        contact.FileAsMapping = FileAsMapping.SurnameCommaGivenName
        contact.Save()



        MsgBox("Contact created!!!")

    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try



End Function
```

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I have the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the folder ID as a parameter for Save method of Contact class.

```
contact.Save(folderId)
```

Where folderId is an ID of your destionation public folder

See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd635209(v=exchg.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd635209%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) for more information

Comment: How to get the `folderId` of the public folder?

Comment: You can get folder id of public folders root as follows: var folderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.PublicFoldersRoot). Next you can search required public folders using FindFolders method and obtain folder id(s) from results.